# How to display custom validation for date picker in ngx-formly/bootstrap

Tags: angular8, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-formly

I am creating dynamic UI/form using ngx-formly/bootstrap(not using material). I want to display datepicker control so I have displyed custom bsdatepicker control using ngx-bootstrap/datepicker. Now I want to do validations on this datepicker e.g IfI have from and to date then From date should not be less than current date or To Date should not be grater than from date. Any help will be appriciated.

```
    //datepicker.html
     <pre><input type="text" 
       id="dob-id" 
       class="form-control calendar" 
       placement="bottom" 
       bsDatepicker
       [formlyAttributes]="field"
       #dobDate="bsDatepicker" 
       [bsConfig]="bsConfig" 
       placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"
       [class.is-invalid]="showError" class=""  style="width: 350px;">
```

took separate component for this and registered in app.modeul

//in scheema

```
{
key: 'date1',
type: 'bsdatepicker',
templateOptions: {
label :'From Date',
required: true,
},
},
{
key: 'date2',
type: 'bsdatepicker',
templateOptions: {
label :'To Date',
required: true,
},
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation is handled by Formly so all you need is to just define validation along with its messages you may check our examples in the docs:

- https://formly.dev/examples/validation/built-in-validations
- https://formly.dev/examples/validation/custom-validation
- https://formly.dev/examples/validation/validation-message

Comment: Thanks. I refereed above link but in my case I am using custom date piker  and it not displaying default required message even if I am declaring it in template option (required: true). So how to display required filed validation message for custom controls in ngx/formly?

Comment: could you please show me an example here is the stackblitz starter example stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

ngx-bootstrap is a wrong tag here, I think